# How can i add pagination to a parent gridview using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am stuck in a situation where i need to add pagination to parent gridview only(I have a nested gridview where i don't want to add paginatiion to child gridview).i have searched for many example but however I couldn't find any solution.Please help me with this. I am stuck on this issue  and could not find any workaround.i am getting input string was not in correct format error on rowcommand event on line
 int id = int.Parse(e.CommandName.ToString());

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GVLeader" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        DataKeyNames="id" OnRowCommand="GVLeader_RowCommand" 
      CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle- 
      CssClass="alt"  PageSize = "15"  AllowSorting="true" 
      AllowPaging="true">   

        <Columns>  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# 
          Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
      Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# 
    Eval("Name") %>' Width="100"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Detail View" ControlStyle- 
      BackColor="#EBEBEB">  
            <ItemTemplate>  
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnplus" Text="Edit Details" 
      CssClass="greenButton" CommandName='<%#Eval("id") %>' 
      CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>' />
               <asp:GridView ID="GVMember" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
       runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
      AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
                        DataKeyNames="id" 
      OnRowCancelingEdit="GVMember_RowCancelingEdit" 
      OnRowEditing="GVMember_RowEditing"   OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting"
                        OnRowUpdating="GVMember_RowUpdating"   
      CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle- 
      CssClass="alt" PageSize = "10"  AllowSorting="true" 
      AllowPaging="true">  
                        <Columns>  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# 
        Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>


             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Emp Salary" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpSalary" runat="server" Text='<%# 
       Eval("EmpSalary") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpSalary" runat="server" Text='<%# 
       Eval("EmpSalary") %>' Width="100"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Emp Address " >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# 
      Eval("Emp Address") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# 
      Eval("Emp Address") %>' Width="100"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>  
    </asp:GridView>  
     </ItemTemplate>  
    </asp:TemplateField>  
        </Columns>  
      </asp:GridView> 

       CodeBehind Code:-


     namespace Final
         {
       public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
      SqlConnection con = new 
      SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["server"].ToString());
      SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("confidential"); //Create 
      sqlconnection  

     SqlDataAdapter da;
     DataTable dt2, dt1;
    Properties objlog = new Properties();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGVLeader();
        }
    }
    protected void GVLeader_RowCommand(object sender, 
    GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
     {
        int id = int.Parse(e.CommandName.ToString());
        int rowindex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        GridView GVMember = 
     (GridView)GVLeader.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("GVMember");
        Button btn = 
    ((Button)GVLeader.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("btnplus"));

        if (btn.Text == "Edit Details")
        {
            btn.Text = "Cancel";
            GVMember.DataSource = LoadGVMember(id);
            GVMember.DataBind();
            GVMember.Visible = true;

        }
        else
        {
            btn.Text = "Edit Details";
            GVMember.Visible = false;
        }

    }
    public void LoadGVLeader()
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from emptable", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GVLeader.DataSource = dt;
        GVLeader.DataBind();
    }
    protected DataTable LoadGVMember(int id)
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from emptable where  ID=" + id, 
    con);
        dt1 = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt1);
        ViewState["dt"] = dt1;
        return dt1;
    }
    protected void GVMember_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView Gv = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)Gv.Parent.Parent;
        int id = 
   int.Parse(GVLeader.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        Gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        Gv.DataSource = LoadGVMember(id);
        Gv.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GVMember_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, 
  GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView Gv = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)Gv.Parent.Parent;
        int id = 
  int.Parse(GVLeader.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        Gv.EditIndex = -1;
        Gv.DataSource = LoadGVMember(id);
        Gv.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GVMember_RowUpdating(object sender, 
   GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView Gv = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)Gv.Parent.Parent;
        int id = 
  int.Parse(GVLeader.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        int id1 = int.Parse(Gv.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        Gv.EditIndex = -1;
        Gv.DataSource = LoadGVMember(id);
        Gv.DataBind();
    }

    protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView Gv = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)Gv.Parent.Parent;
        Label lbldeleteid = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblID");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete FROM emptable where ID='" + 
      Convert.ToInt32(GVLeader.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()) + "'", 
      con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        LoadGVLeader();
      }

     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove pagination props from child grid(GVMember)

change

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GVMember" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
       runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
      AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
                        DataKeyNames="id" 
      OnRowCancelingEdit="GVMember_RowCancelingEdit" 
      OnRowEditing="GVMember_RowEditing"   OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting"
                        OnRowUpdating="GVMember_RowUpdating"   
      CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle- 
      CssClass="alt" PageSize = "10"  AllowSorting="true" 
      AllowPaging="true">
```

with

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVMember" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
       runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
      AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
                        DataKeyNames="id" 
      OnRowCancelingEdit="GVMember_RowCancelingEdit" 
      OnRowEditing="GVMember_RowEditing"   OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting"
                        OnRowUpdating="GVMember_RowUpdating"   
      CssClass="mGrid" AlternatingRowStyle- 
      CssClass="alt"   AllowSorting="true">
```